# Django i18n get_language_info_list and get_available_languages provide different language code

Tags: python, django

With `{% get_current_language as CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}` ,
`{{ CURRENT_LANGUAGE }}` shows `nl-nl`

With `{% get_available_languages as AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES %}` ,
`{{ AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES }}` shows `[('nl-NL', 'Nederlands'), ('en', 'Engels')]`

With `{% get_language_info_list for AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES as LANGUAGES %}` ,
`{{ LANGUAGES }}` shows `[{'bidi': False, 'code': 'nl', 'name': 'Dutch', 'name_local': 'Nederlands', 'name_translated': 'Nederlands'}, {'bidi': False, 'code': 'en', 'name': 'English', 'name_local': 'English', 'name_translated': 'Engels'}]`

Settings:

```
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code
LANGUAGE_CODE = "nl-NL"

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#languages
LANGUAGES = [
    ('nl-NL', _('Dutch')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]
```

In `{{ LANGUAGES }}` I expect `code` to be `nl-NL` and not `nl`. Anyone that can explain this discrepancy?

Django version:
`Django==4.2.10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `nl` is present in `django/django/conf/locale`. Based on `LANG_INFO` (from django.conf.locale import LANG_INFO). I found it is happening here `generic_lang_code = lang_code.split("-")[0]`:

```
def get_language_info(lang_code):
    from django.conf.locale import LANG_INFO

    try:
        lang_info = LANG_INFO[lang_code]
        if "fallback" in lang_info and "name" not in lang_info:
            info = get_language_info(lang_info["fallback"][0])
        else:
            info = lang_info
    except KeyError:
        if "-" not in lang_code:
            raise KeyError("Unknown language code %s." % lang_code)
        generic_lang_code = lang_code.split("-")[0]
        try:
            info = LANG_INFO[generic_lang_code]
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError(
                "Unknown language code %s and %s." % (lang_code, generic_lang_code)
            )

    if info:
        info["name_translated"] = gettext_lazy(info["name"])
    return info
```